# Angular 10.1 "This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection."

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project I try to move the spinner service out from my components and now I get `Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.` message. But the VSCode linter don't say anything.

The full error message is this:

```
Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.
    at Module.ɵɵinvalidFactory (core.js:14675)
    at Object.AppDataService_Factory [as factory] (app-data.service.ts:36)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11289)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11111)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24243)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11122)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24243)
    at Object.get (core.js:22142)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:4079)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14651)
```

...but the `app-data.service.ts:36` is only the end of a function. (Below I marked it.)

The `banner.component.ts` file:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner-list',
  templateUrl: './banner-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner-list.component.scss']
})
export class BannerListComponent extends BaseListComponent<BannerInterface> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private appDataService: AppDataService<BannerInterface>,
    private helpreService: HelperService,
  ) {
    super(Banner);
  }

  // ...

  loadDatas(): Observable<any> {
    // create observable function
    const getAll$ = this.appDataService.proxy.getAll().pipe(
      map((result: any) => {
        // ...
      }),
    );

    return this.appDataService.start(getAll$, 'banner getAll');
  }
}
```

The `app-data.service.ts` file:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppDataService<T extends BaseModelInterface<T>> {
  private spinner: SpinnerServiceInterface = AppModule.InjectorInstance.get(SpinnerService);
  proxy: ProxyServiceInterface<T> = new ProxyService(this.model);

  constructor(
    private model: T,
  ) { }

  start(pipeInstance: Observable<any>, spinnerName: string = 'spinner'): Observable<any> {
    return of(1).pipe(
      // switch on spinner
      tap(() => this.spinner.on(spinnerName)),

      // run observable pipe instance
      switchMap(() => pipeInstance),

      // switch off spinner
      tap(() => this.spinner.off(spinnerName)),
    );
  } // <--------- this is the 36. line
}
```

The `ProxyService` is from the `ddata-core` package, but this is the constructor:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProxyService<T extends BaseModelInterface<T>> extends DataServiceAbstract<T> {
  private type: new () => T;

  constructor(
    private instance: T,
  ) {
    super(instance);
    // ...
  }

  getAll(pageNumber: number = 0): Observable<any> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I'm stucked with this. Any idea where should I looking the solution of `his constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`, you are telling Angular to create an instance of your `AppDataService` to add it in the Root module's provider. However, it does not know how to create this instance with your constructor, as it cannot inject a `T` instance for the model.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem because the `super()` call was forgotten in the inheriting class. Make sure not to forget it.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
@StoreConfig({ name: fictive })
class FictiveStore extends AppModelStore {
  // !!!!!!!!!!!!! Forgotten to put that here
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

export abstract class AppModelStore extends Store {
  constructor() {
    // Initial state
    super(initial);
  }
}
```